# Xcode 9.4.1 "No accounts with iTunes Connect access"

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, xcode9

From yesterday evening on I always get an Error when trying to upload an archive from Xcode 9.4.1

"No accounts with iTunes Connect access"

I tried everything I could find on this forum and elsewhere but nothing seemed to work. I'm still getting this error over all.

This is what I tried yet:

- Closing Xcode and reopen
- Removing the account from Xcode and adding it again (also with closing Xcode in between)
- Restarting the Mac
- Using my other Mac
- Deleting all cache Files from Xcode (Derived Data, …)
- Uninstalling Xcode and reinstalling
- Exporting an *.ipa and using Application Loader instead. But I couldn't sign into Application Loader even with an App specific password it wouldn't let me sign in.

Well, that's about everything I tried the last 24 hours without success. Hopefully someone of you guys can help me out. I also contacted Developer Support but they'll get back to me in 1 to 2 business days…

And here I got a screenshot of the error message
[image: Error Message Screenshot]

Answer (score -5, accepted):

I managed to fix it by creating a new Apple ID and add it to iTunes Connect. Then add it to Xcode and try to upload. It worked.